# Import javascript class in vueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use a javascript class in may Vue application.

My class looks like:

```
class className { 
   constructor() { 
       ... 
   }  

   function1() { 
       ... 
   }  

   static funtion2() {
        ... 
   } 
}
```

I tried to import this class in my application like:

- import className from './fileName.js';
- var {className} = require('./fileName.js')

In all cases I receive when I want to call a function of the class (`className.function2()`): the function is undefined.

Comment: do not forget to export you "class" from the module where it is declared

Comment: Did you spell `require` right?

Comment: you said `function2` does not work, does `function1` work?

Comment: do you use webpack or similar?

Comment: @GibboK  - did you mean to export the class where I imported? I'm using from the same module.  I'm using webpack.

Comment: @qjnr - the function1 doesn't work, and I can't call the constructor. I tried to call the static methods.

Comment: Is `className` defined? Or is `className` also `undefined`?

Comment: `classname` has something like this:  {__esModule: true}
__esModule: true
__proto__:Object

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to export the class to be able to import/require it

```
//1. For import syntax
export default class className {...}

//2. For require syntax
class className {}
module.exports.className = className
//or
module.exports = {
    className: className
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. I see "module.exports" is undefined for me. Unable to set
module.exports.MyClass = MyClass

TypeError: Cannot set property 'MyClass' of undefined

Answer (score 9):

Using `import/export`, you'd use

```
export class className {}
```

and

```
import {className} from '<file>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare to @baao answer, I add the `default` keyword for the export.

```
export default class className {}
```

and in the `component.vue` file:

```
<script>
import className from '<pathToFile>';
...
</script>
```