# How to declare javascript class instance in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to get access to the data stored in canvas.js in my vue.js. For this I have to create the instance of canvas in my vue. But I have some issues with this.

I found the [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215005/import-javascript-class-in-vuejs) as mine but the answer doesnt set up for me, I also tried require.
I also find some [solution](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-solve-unexpected-identifier-modules/) with ES6, but I dont use ES6, but I also tried it, not working.

This what I type in Vue.js

```
import Canvas from './canvas.js';
```

Canvas.js

```
export default class Canvas{
contructor(){
    this.devices = ["5", "15"];
}
```

I wonder why does first solution didnt help me, bcz my problem is very similar. If I comment with "//" the import in Vue.js everything working fine. Maybe there are another solution without using import, but I need to have access to the data stored in Canvas.

P.s pls dont recommend to use components bcs im planning to store another class instance in devices of Canvas, and there would be too much of useless components(imho bcs im noob in vue)

UPD: My issue that the code doest not compile after "import", and I have this . [image]

but If i put "import" to comment "//" the situation is like 
[image]

UPD2: The full Vue.js file

```
//import Canvas from './canvas.js';
  var app1 = new Vue({
     el: '#vue1',
     data: {
        arr2: [8, 7, 6, 5]
     },
     methods: {
        addArr1: function(num){
        this.arr2.push(num)
     }
   }
 });
```

canvas.js

```
export default class Canvas{
contructor(){
    this.devices = ["5", "15"];
}
```

my index.html

```
<div id="vue1">
    <ul v-for="ar in arr2">
        <li>{{ ar }}</li>
    </ul>
    <button v-on:click="addArr1(15)">CLICK</button>
</div>
```

Comment: what are your issues?

Comment: How are you trying to access `devices`? Because with the current code, you have to create a `Canvas` instance first.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the question, I updated the topic

Comment: How are you transpiling your code?

Comment: @DaveNewton im not sure what do u mean of transpilling, google translate cant translate this word. But if u are talking about architecture, I have Vue.js and Canvas.js, in Vue.js I'm trying to import Canvas class to use it, but code doesn't compile after import string

Comment: @AndrewCastellano Sorry for not clarifying the question, I updated the topic

Comment: @ChrisG Sorry for not clarifying the question, I updated the topic

Comment: How are you including the Vue library?  Are you running the `vue-cli` which means webpack, or are you including each `*.js` file individually in a `<script src="whatev.js">`?  Webpack transpiles ES module code to make it run like "regular" JS.

Comment: @zero298 i dont use ES, I just include script <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script> and <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

Comment: `import` isn't officially supported in a browser environment yet. Transpiling means taking ES6 modules (files) that use `import` and `export` and turning them into a single `bundle.js` file. You seem to be using pure client-side Vue, so you can't use `import` like that. What you can do is put a `<script>` in your HTML and use `const Canvas = { devices: ["5", "15"] };`, now your Vue script should be able to use `Canvas.devices`.

Comment: @ChrisG ane other option if i dont use ES?

Comment: @ChrisG I added canvas.js script in html and tried to use it with&without declaring canvas instance in vue, but it doesnt work. Where should I add const Canvas = { devices: ["5", "15"] }, is it possible to modify it if its const?

Comment: I meant like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lez8an6g/

Comment: @ChrisG in my opinion this is too low performance solution, and I dont see the ways to modify the devices array from Vue.js. Do u have any other solution? I'd prefer the one to have access to canvas from vue.js without installing any webpack or other libraries(if ES is library, anyway just using pure vue)

Comment: The fiddle isn't using webpack, and the performance isn't impacted anyway even if it did. And `Canvas.devices` can be modified just fine. I updated the fiddle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using ES Modules in the browser requires you to use a different mechanism to load the scripts.  Essentially, you should have an "entry point" that you load and that can import varying modules you need to run.  This entry point should be defined using a `<script type="module" src="whatever.js">`, note the `type="module`.  You can read about it here: [MDN `<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

If you don't use `type="module"`, you can't use `import` unless you run a transpiler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).  Vue has a bootstrapping application that helps you set up a Vue project that leverages webpack here: [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/).

Your application will effectively look something like this:

### Canvas.js

```js
export default class Canvas {
  contructor() {
    this.devices = ["5", "15"];
  }
}
```

### my-cool-script.js

```js
import Vue from "https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.0/dist/vuex.esm.js";
import Canvas from "./Canvas.js";

var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#vue1',
  data: {
    arr2: [8, 7, 6, 5]
  },
  methods: {
    addArr1: function(num) {
      this.arr2.push(num)
    }
  }
});
```

### index.html

```html
<script src="my-cool-script.js" type="module"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

If you do not use `type="module"`, you **cannot use `import`** without transpiling.  Your project would basically look like this:

### Canvas.js

```js
class Canvas {
  contructor() {
    this.devices = ["5", "15"];
  }
}
```

### my-cool-script.js

```js
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '#vue1',
  data: {
    arr2: [8, 7, 6, 5]
  },
  methods: {
    addArr1: function(num) {
      this.arr2.push(num)
    }
  }
});
```

### index.html

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script src="Canvas.js"></script>
<script src="my-cool-script.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I dont use ES, if it only to add 
import Vue from "https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.0/dist/vuex.esm.js";
I did it, and followed ur instruction, but still not working

Comment: @Ordec Unless you use `type="module"`, you cannot use `import` without running through a transpiler like webpack.  You'll have to include both scripts explicitly in the HTML and remove the `import`.

Comment: idk why, but any attempt of using import causes not compiling the code below of it

Comment: ok, I wonder will my code work, if i will add <script src="canvas" type="module"></script>? I did it, its not working, or I necesseraly have to use webpack TO MAKE MY CODE WORK (caps bcs that the goal). In the condition that I dont use webpack and ES, are there any possible chance to make access to canvas?